# Call known function (with parameters) in class whose name is defined by string variable

Tags: java, function, class, variables

I have a bunch of classes of various names and each has a performLogic function that accepts a number of preset parameters (always the same):

```
public final class DoSomeAction extends SetupAction {
    public void performLogic(param1, param2...
```

I want a way where I can call it like this:

```
String actionName = "DoSomeAction";
actionName.performLogic(param1, param2...);
```

Hope this is clear what I am trying to do.

Thanks for feedback and pointing me towards class.forName()
After some further research I was able to implement the following:

```
try {
    Class actionClass = Class.forName(blockAction);

    Object obj = actionClass.newInstance();

    Class[] parameterTypes = new Class[2];
    parameterTypes[0] = String.class;
    parameterTypes[1] =  String.class;

    Method performLogic = actionClass.getDeclaredMethod("performLogic", parameterTypes);

    performLogic.invoke(obj, param1, param2);
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
    cat.error("Class not found: " + e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Reflection is the key. You can instantiate a class by a given class name (together with the package name) and invoke the function. See Class.forName("full.package.Classname")

Comment: After calling Class.forName() you have to invoke .newInstance() on that class object. After casting it to the right class you will be able to call that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Reflection

```
Object action = ???; // perhaps you need .newInstance() for action class
                     // Hopefully you have a interface with performLogic

String methodName = "performLogic";
try {
    Method method = action.getClass().getMethod(methodName, param1.class, param2.class);
    method.invoke(action, param1, param2);
} catch (SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException e) {
    // Error by get Method
} catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {        
    // Error by call Method
}
```